# What is the status of JMX 2.0?

Tags: java, jmx

It was supposed to be released with Java 7, but the status is [Dormant](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=255). On the other hand, the same page says

> Use generics in the JMX API, for example have `MBeanServer.queryNames` return `Set<ObjectName>` rather than just `Set`.

and this did happen [in Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServer.html#queryNames%28javax.management.ObjectName,%20javax.management.QueryExp%29). So, did some of the changes get in? Are there significant differences between Java 6 and Java 7 JMX implementations? Looking at Javadocs, I didn't notice any, but this only covers the API.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I asked this question also to the current product manager for JMX at Oracle, [Tuva Palm](https://plus.google.com/118308589850181935930/posts) some times ago (September 2011), and she promised me, that JMX 2.0 is not dead and there will be a technical roadmap in Q1/2012.

However, nothing have happened until now and even worse, [JSR-255](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=255), the JMX 2.0 spec (but also [JSR-262](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=262), ther WebService connector stuff) has been marked as [withdrawn](https://jcp.org/en/introduction/glossary#status) since 2016 with the following reason:

> JSR 255 specified changes to javax.management.* which were subsequently abandoned due to lack of resources, and were not included in the Java SE 6 or 7 Platforms. (The changes were distinct from other changes to javax.management.* specified by JSRs 3, 160, and 336 for inclusion in the Java SE 6 and 7 Platforms.) It was determined in 2014 that future changes to JMX technology would be specified directly by the umbrella JSR for the Java SE Platform.

So JMX 2.0 in its original form is factually dead.

Comment: Staffan Larsen wrote me, that JMX 2.0 won't be in Java 8 either ;-(. Next chance: Java 9 (late 2015).

Comment: BTW, Jaroslav Bachorík will be leading the Effort for reviving JMX 2.0 , according to Staffan Larsen.

Comment: We can ask if JMX 2.0 is dead, but even if it's not "dead", we can ask if anyone will use it. e.g. [JSR 373: JavaTM EE Management API 2.0](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=373) is considering making JMX _server management_ "Proposed Optional" on Java EE servers vs. a REST management API (JMX would still be available, just not used to manage the server).

Comment: JSR-373 is dead as well as it will be removed from the Java EE 8 spec as announced at JavaOne 2016.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, [it was postponed to JDK 8](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2009/06/jsr_255_jmx_api.html), and all already made changes reverted, so JDK 7 final implementation should be the same as JDK 6.