# What is the JMX Alternative for enterprise application

Tags: java, jmx, application-management

With the future of JMX 2.0 [questionable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461617/what-is-the-status-of-jmx-2-0) as of now, JavaDMK and OpenDMk not [active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928462/is-java-dmk-or-opendmk-still-supported-by-oracle), what is the best alternative we have for application management and monitoring available? Any effort from Spring,Apache camps or alike?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is still the default supported JMX implementation available. And it will be supported for the foreseeable future. Meaning that all the performance, security and feature bugs will be evaluated and potentially fixed.

BTW, is there something in the JMX 2.0 proposal the lack of what makes the JMX unusable for you?

Comment: I am not saying JMX is unusable in its current stage, it just needs enhancement that enterprise apps need now-a-days. 
For me most critical feature I need now is cascading support and more client-side connector support to provide a comprehensive monitoring and management package. Although connector alternatives are available but they should be part of JMX package.